# Ruby, delayed_job, Roo - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, delayed-job, roo

In my controller

```
  def upload
    @file = params[:file_xlsx]
    Category.delay.upload_process(@file.tempfile, params[:id])
    redirect_to action: "show", id: params[:id]
  end
```

On My Model

```
  def self.upload_process(file, id)

    xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
    .........
  end
```

The error:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Works perfect without "delayed_job", but does not work with "delayed_job", what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.put `delay` at the end

```
def upload
  @file = params[:file_xlsx]
  Category.upload_process(@file, params[:id]).delay
  redirect_to action: "show", id: params[:id]
end
```